# Cannot set React Native Animated value to View component CSS style

Tags: animation, view, react-native, animated

I am trying to have a View component style animate. I am following the examples listed here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

But, when I render my component, I get the error:

> [tid:com.facebook.React.ShadowQueue][RCTConvert.m:55] Error setting property 'height' of RCTView with tag #7: JSON value '{
>       "_animation" = "";
>       "_children" =     (
>       );
>       "_listeners" =     {
>       };
>       "_offset" = 0;
>       "_value" = 200;
>   }' of type NSDictionary cannot be converted to NSNumber

This is how I'm setting the Animated value in my constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      titleContainerHeight: new Animated.Value(200),
    }
  }
```

And here is my view:

```
<View style={[styles.titleContainer,{height:this.state.titleContainerHeight}]}>
  <Text style={[{color: 'white'}]}>App logo here</Text>
</View>
```

Seems like I'm going everything just how the documentation describes, and I'm doing the same thing in another component without getting any errors. So, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ah never mind, I found what I was doing wrong. I forgot to use the "Animated.View" component specifically. This works:

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.titleContainer,{height:this.state.titleContainerHeight}]}>
  <Text style={[{color: 'white'}]}>App logo here</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: Thanks I just did this too. It is easy to forget when you start out with a normal view and then want to 'just' add animation to it later.

Comment: Thank you for following up with the solution. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: Finally I find the answer. Thank you sir/mam. This is one of those weird questions where a google search doesn't quickly find the solution.